# How to vertical align radio buttons

Tags: html, css

So right now i have three radio buttons that are **aligned horizontally** by default, but instead i want them **to** be **aligned vertically**. How do i do that the correct way?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Custom Radio Button</h1>
  <label for="myRadioId" class = "radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class = "radio__input">
    Mercedes Benz
  </label>
  <label for="myRadioId2" class = "radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId2" class = "radio__input">
    BMW
  </label>
  <label for="myRadioId3" class = "radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId3" class = "radio__input">
    Volkswagen
  </label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `inline-flex` with `flex`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Custom Radio Button</h1>
  <label for="myRadioId" class = "radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class = "radio__input">
    Mercedes Benz
  </label>
  <label for="myRadioId2" class = "radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId2" class = "radio__input">
    BMW
  </label>
  <label for="myRadioId3" class = "radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId3" class = "radio__input">
    Volkswagen
  </label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: inline-flex;` use `display: table;` in CSS.

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio {
display: table;
align-items: center;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display:block;` or `display:flex;`(as mentioned in the answer list).

> Try to avoid `radio` as selector class name since it is a **keyword** and it is not good way to use in that way.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/87xt9czq/3/) to playaround.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Custom Radio Button</h1>
  <label for="myRadioId" class="radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class = "radio__input">
    Mercedes Benz
  </label>
  <label for="myRadioId2" class="radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId2" class = "radio__input">
    BMW
  </label>
  <label for="myRadioId3" class="radio">
    <input type = "radio" name = "myRadioField" id="myRadioId3" class = "radio__input">
    Volkswagen
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```